# Repository save not rollbacked if send message fails

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-transactions, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Given the following code :

```java
@RabbitListener
public void process(Message myMessage) {
    Event event = ..get event from myMessage
    handleMessage(event);
}

@Transactional
public void handleMessage(Event event) {
    ObjectToSend objecToSend = ...get objectToSend from event
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange1, routingKey1, objectToSend); // line 1 :  supposte that at this point rabbit is still connected 
    persistService.save(new MyEntity()); // line 2
    doSomethingElse(); // line 3 : suppose that at this point rabbit is disconnected (network failure)
}
```

I notice that if persistService.save fails then :

1. objecToSend  is not sent  (and this is fine)
2. the original myMessage in the RabbitListener is sent to DLQ (and this is fine)

but if persistService.save succeed and convertAndSend fails (because of a rabbit server connection failure after persistService.save ), original myMessage go back in DLQ (this is ok) but the problem is that MyEntity is not rollbacked.

What am I doing wrong ?

`persistService.save(myEntity)` should be executed ONLY IF rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend is REALLY sent.

The only solution I found is to use "publish confirms" and BLOCK after `convertAndSend(message, correlationData)` and then using a `correlationData.getFuture()` with `future.get` (possibly with a Timeout) and only after "positive" confirm received confirm I can proceed invoking method persistService.save()
Is it the right solution ? (I suspect this could be "slow)

Consider even that if the publish of objectToSend  fail I must  reject myMessage to the DLQ.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `channelTransacted` on the template but the performance will be similar to waiting for the confirmation because it requires a round trip to the broker.

That will use a local transaction which will commit when the send completes.

Or, add your transaction manager to the listener container and it will synchronize the rabbit transaction with the DB transaction.

Comment: First of all thank you Gary for your time. I specified setChannelTransacted both in the ListenerContainerFactory and in the RabbitTemplate. I observed that in the face of a failed convertAndSend the "persistService.save" is rolled back only if I use the following tr.manager : ChainedTransactionManager(JpaTransactionManager, RabbitTransactionManager); 
I know 'ChainedTransactionManager' is "deprecated" but I don't see any better alternative. If you have suggestions you're welcome.